# Load div based on url or ID

Tags: javascript

I want a certain feature `div container-new` to load on certain pages only. My theory is to run a if statement on load to say if page url equals `/A2017.html` or `/A2018.html` or `/A2017.html` load `<div id="conrainer_new"></div>` else don't load.
Is this achievable with JS or jQuery.

I have tried this but div still loads on all urls. im sure there is a better more robust solution to this. also I need to be a able to include multiple urls in the rule.

```
if (window.location.search..search(/A2017.html)) 
  document.getElementById('conrainer_new').display = 'block'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a similar approach but with using `indexOf` instead. If the string for the page name is found, indexOf will return the position instead of -1 so the condition will be true.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/A2017.html') != -1) {
    document.getElementById('container_new').display = 'block'
}
```

Comment: Note that this only checks for one of the values the OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple values to check for in the URL you can use a regular expression:

```js
if (window.location.match(/\/A2017.html|\/A2018.html/i)
  document.getElementById('conrainer_new').display = 'block'
```

Also note that if there will never be a querystring on the URL you can add `$` to the regex to ensure that the match is only at the end of the URL string, eg `/\/A2017.html$|\/A2018.html$/i`